# What happened to Touka's mom?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

We know what happened to Touka and Ayato's dad, but what about their mom? We don't hear anything about her at all.

Answer (score 2):

In Tokyo ghoul:re ch. 70-71 it is revealed that Touka's mother (who was also Renji Yomo's sister) was killed by Arima. I believe the exact incident was not shown, but presumably she held off Arima while Arata (Touka's dad) escaped with the kids.

Comment: Oh I soo didn’t know that